# calculating the probability of winning a streak, what approach should I take?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, simulation, dynamic-programming

Here is the game:

> $A$ plays against $B$. Each round, $A$ has probability $a$ of winning, $B$ has a probability $b$ of winning, and the probability of a draw is $d$. So $a+b+d=1$. Each round is independent. Winning criteria is the one who first reaches a streak of $N$. Let's say $N=10$. If a draw occurs, the streak is reset. So the game continues until there is a winner.
>
> How to calculate the probability of $A$ or $B$ winning the game?

What are some approaches I can take? Is there a mathematical way to calculate this rather than running simulations? (I tried running simulations, but I'm not satisfied with the result. If $N$ is fairly big, it takes a long time to run.)

Comment: This is an open challenge problem from [IBM's monthly Ponder This](https://research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/February2024.html). You've renamed Alice->A and Bob->B, and changed N, but its the same problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question on an open contest problem.